# What if your make (or build) target is the existence of certain contents in a file

Tags: build, makefile

The typical build targets for make and other build systems is a file or directory. I am building [a system similar BSD-ports for emacs packages](https://github.com/metaperl/edan).

I just realized that my target for each package was not truly accurate - it's not that the file [edan.el](https://github.com/metaperl/edan/blob/master/edan.el) needs to be newer than its prerequisites. It must be newer than the prerequisites and it must contain

```
(provide '[% pkg %])
```

Where `pkg` is the package that has just been downloaded, unpacked, and byte-compiled.

Is there a way to do this with make? Does any other build system handle this sort of thing?

Comment: What besides the build system will be modifying `edan/el`? And what do you want the build system to do if it rebuilds `edan.el` and it still doesn't contain that line?

Comment: Nothing will modify the build systems besides the Makefile in the package being built. If it doesnt contain that line, then it will go through the build process, but you just gave me an idea. Instead of modifying edan.el being the check, I can add a file to the edan directory once the build completes and check for the existence of that.

Comment: Think about it: if nothing else can modify `edan.el`, and if the build process is sure to modify `edan.el` correctly, then `edan.el` will be correct if and only if it is newer than its prerequisites. You don't have to check its contents, or introduce a dummy file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the case that you want the target to contain the right data.  You don't want `foo.o` to have no relation to the contents of `foo.c`, for example.  The timestamps are merely a proxy for this.  You have to trust that the tools actually do the right thing.

It sounds like the real complication here is that the dependencies are dynamic.  The file `edan.el` depends on the list of all currently installed and managed packages, which can change.  But you can, of course, represent this data as a file.  I expect you already do have a file that has a list of the active packages, actually.

(You possibly also want to depend on the actual packages too.  You should be able to write a script to munge this data into a depend file that is include in the main `Makefile`.)